# How to change the title of the Markdown file by language?

Tags: doxygen

I'm new to using Doxygen. As I mentioned in the title, I want to change the name of the title I gave in the Markdown file according to the output language. 
For example, I can give a static title like this:

```
@page AIPage AIHeader
```

In this way, I can add something to the page in the output language I choose:

```
\~english Hello
\~turkish Merhaba
```

Unfortunately, when I use the same usage in the title, I cannot get any results:

```
@page AIPage \~english Hello|\~turkish Merhaba
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for all your support in advance.

Note: I'm using version 1.8.17

Comment: Please always specify the doxygen version used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following construct:

```
\~turkish
@page pg1 Merhaba
\~english
@page pg1 hello
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem, but a different problem occurred. This really changes the name but additionally it produces an html file in the filename. For example, I see both Hello and pg1 in the tree view.Also, the content of the pg1 page seems completely empty.

Comment: Is your filename also e.g. pg1.md?

Comment: Yes It's pg1.md