# Doxygen generates empty pages when I use multiple languages

Tags: doxygen

I had a problem with multiple languages but in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61365027/how-to-change-the-title-of-the-markdown-file-by-language) and @albert help me and I solved the problem. But when I do this a new problem arose. When I use multiple languages on markdown files, Doxygen generates new empty page in the treeview. For example:

```
\~turkish
@page Page1 TRPage1
@tableofcontents
\~endturkish

\~english
@page Page1 ENPage1
@tableofcontents
\~endenglish
```

Let's say OUTPUT_LANGUAGE is Turkish. It generates TRPage1 with content but it generates empty Page1 too. When I look HTML directory, file names look like this:

```
TRPage1 : _t_r_page1
Page1 : md__c_1__users__username__documents__projects__projectname_documentation_doc_pages__pages__page1.html
```

I hope you understand me. I don't want to see an empty page in my treeview.

My Doxygen version is: 1.8.17
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I think at the moment this is not possible, I do remember that some effort has been invested in the case that a Markdown block started with empty lines to retrieve the first non empty line to get to the page title. Probably we need some construct for `\~...` settings (and `\if...` constructs as well. Probably best is to file an issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new .

Comment: Note `\~endturkish` and `\~endenglish` aren't valid language ids, it should be `\~`. I'm amazed that no warning appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not withstanding my comment, that was about the `\~`:

> I think at the moment this is not possible, I do remember that some effort has been invested in the case that a Markdown block started with empty lines to retrieve the first non empty line to get to the page title. Probably we need some construct for \~... settings (and \if... constructs as well)

There is a bit of a mean trick possible:

```
\cond turkish
@page Page1 TRPage1
@tableofcontents
\endcond

\cond english
@page Page1 ENPage1
@tableofcontents
\endcond
```

and set in the doxygen configuration file either:

```
ENABLED_SECTIONS  = english
```

or

```
ENABLED_SECTIONS  = turkish
```

Note with `\if` it looks like that it doesn't work as `@page` will immediately terminate the if-block and finding later on a sole `\endif`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Albert. It works with this trick. I can say that the problem is solved.